# How to store Json output value in variable through Ansible

Tags: ansible, co

In Ansible,I am using REST API...I want value of `clientid` from below code and want to use it in another task..I am using ansible uri module.

```
 debug: var=clients.json.clientProperties[3].client.clientEntity.clientId
      when: name==clients.json.clientProperties[{{ item }}].client.clientEntity.clientName
      with_sequence: start=0 end={{clients.json.clientProperties|length-1}}
```

I want to store "16" in one variable and need to pass another url

Comment: [set_fact](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html) module?

Answer (score 0):

```
- debug: var=clients.json.clientProperties[3].client.clientEntity.clientId
  when: name == clients.json.clientProperties[ item ].client.clientEntity.clientName
  with_sequence: start=0 end="{{clients.json.clientProperties|length-1}}"
  register: result
```

The vars you are looking for will be available at `result.results[].item`. You can loop over `result.results` or access the results individually with `result.results[0]`, `result.results[1]`, etc.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it. Here In our code when name matches with clientname I want to store value of clientId. I don't want whole json array file.

Comment: Without more context I'm not sure I can give a better answer because you are doing this in a loop. You can't save multiple values to the same var except as a list as I'm doing here, meaning you could overwrite a value you want before you can use it.

Comment: copy: content={{clients.json.clientProperties[3].client.clientEntity.clientId}} dest="/tmp/result.txt"
      when: name==clients.json.clientProperties[{{ item }}].client.clientEntity.clientName
      with_sequence: start=0 end={{clients.json.clientProperties|length-1}}

Comment: here in copy content I am manually passing [3] but I want to pass item instead of [3]...But it is giving  {"failed": true, "msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'